# Why does my Prolog predicate not work, when it's an exact copy of the one in Clocksin & Mellish that does work?

Tags: prolog

Sorry for the vague title, but I couldn't find a more specific way to phrase it.

I'm working my way through *Programming In Prolog* by Clocksin & Mellish (4th edition in case it makes any difference), and am stuck in section 3.5, where they implement a predicate `aless/2` that is true if the first argument is alphabetically less than the second. For example, the following would be true...

```
aless(a, b).
aless(ab, ac).
```

...but the following would be false (because the two arguments are equal)...

```
aless(a, a).
```

I read their rules (on page 57), and their explanation of the use of `name/2` to convert a string to a list of integers, and attempted to write the code myself.

When my code didn't work, I turned the page to see how they had implemented it, and was pleased to see that I had done exactly the same as them (to within the choice of variable names), including an optimisation they added on afterwards.

My code looks like this...

```
aless(W1, W2) :-
  name(W1, L1),
  name(W2, L2),
  alessx(L1, L2).

alessx([], [_|_]).
alessx([H1|_], [H2|_]) :- H1 < H2.
alessx([H,T1], [H,T2]) :- alessx(T1,T2).
```

Apart from the fact that they used variable names like `X`, `Y` and so on, which I thought weren't very descriptive, my code seems to be exactly the same as theirs. However, although it is true for the following...

```
aless(a, b).
```

..it is false for...

```
aless(ab, ac).
```

Anyone able to explain why my code isn't working?

In case it makes any difference, I'm using SWI Prolog 9.0.4 on Windows 11.

Thanks

Comment: `[H,T1]` and `[H,T2]` must be written as `[H|T1]` and `[H|T2]`, respectively.

Comment: @slago Aaaaarrrrgggghh! I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake! I've started at this for so long and missed it! Thanks.